# What do these lines in the dock mean?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, dock

As in the picture below. I get that the dots underneath each icon are to indicate that the app is running. But what do the lines mean? Is this, as I'm inclined to think, a bug in OS X? Or do they actually have meaning?

Every once in a while, usually one of these pops up and stays there forever until I reboot...

[image: Strange lines in dock...]

Answer (score 2):

It is a download indicator.  If the download failed, you can most likely remove the offending file from the Download folder.

Comment: Really? How do I find out from which download?

Comment: If you go into the Download folder, you should see another file with the progress bar superimposed over the icon.

Answer (score 0):

It means that something is downloading, but if it fails it shouldn't be there. Try to move the icon to another place. Or remove it from dock then add it back.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in OS X, you can use `killall Dock` command to restart the Dock:

- Launch the Terminal: Applications > Utilities > Terminal
- Enter the command: `killall Dock`
- Press the Enter key on the keyboard

Comment: I can surely say that it's NOT a bug. OP hasn't mentioned which OSX it is but quite sure it is Yosemite and i am using that.

Comment: I'm on Yosemite too, and see this bug on both laptop and desktop.
(also take a look to the question tags: `osx-yosemite` is there)

Comment: There is no mention of this being a bug. If you have strong enough proof that this is a bug, post it in your answer. Few users having a same issue does not make it a bug. Have around 5k users using Yosemite in my office & nobody has mentioned this ever